# SwiftUI - Not able to search and toggle in a list

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a list of cars with a toggle button next to each car. There is also a SearchBar at top.
Currently, toogle works fine when search bar is empty. When I type something in search bar, it neither filters the list nor toggle maintains its position. How can I maintain toggle position for each car when list is filtered?

For instance, if I select top three cars without search text. Now I start typing in the search bar, top three toggles remain enabled.

[image]

```
struct Car: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var name: String
    var selected: Bool = false
}
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var cars = [Car(name: "Subaru WRX", selected: false), Car(name:"Tesla Model 3",selected: false), Car(name:"Porsche 911 sjfnewif ewihf dwehifiw eufhwueif uhewfuwe u",selected: false), Car(name:"Renault Zoe",selected: false), Car(name:"DeLorean",selected: false), Car(name:"Mitsubishi Lancer",selected: false), Car(name:"Audi RS6", selected:false),Car(name:"Subaru WRX",selected: false), Car(name:"Tesla Model 3",selected: false), Car(name:"Porsche 911",selected: false), Car(name:"Renault Zoe",selected: false), Car(name:"DeLorean",selected: false), Car(name:"Mitsubishi Lancer",selected: false), Car(name:"Audi RS6", selected:false),
                Car(name:"Subaru WRX",selected: false), Car(name:"Tesla Model 3",selected: false), Car(name:"Porsche 911",selected: false), Car(name:"Renault Zoe",selected: false), Car(name:"DeLorean",selected: false), Car(name:"Mitsubishi Lancer",selected: false), Car(name:"Audi RS6",selected:false),
        Car(name:"Subaru WRX",selected: false), Car(name:"Tesla Model 3",selected: false), Car(name:"Porsche 911",selected: false), Car(name:"Renault Zoe",selected: false), Car(name:"DeLorean",selected: false), Car(name:"Mitsubishi Lancer",selected: false), Car(name:"Audi RS6", selected:false),
        Car(name:"Subaru WRX",selected: false), Car(name:"Tesla Model 3",selected: false), Car(name:"Porsche 911",selected: false), Car(name:"Renault Zoe",selected: false), Car(name:"DeLorean",selected: false), Car(name:"Mitsubishi Lancer",selected: false), Car(name:"Audi RS6", selected: false)]
    @State var showAlert = false
    @State private var searchText : String = ""
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            VStack {
                ScrollView {
                    VStack (alignment: .leading) {
                        SearchBar(text: $searchText, placeholder: "Car name")
                        Button(action: {
                            self.showAlert = true
                            print("Button tapped!")
                        }) {
                            Text("Browse by category").foregroundColor(Color.black).padding(.leading).font(.system(size: 15))
                        }.alert(isPresented: $showAlert) {
                            Alert(title: Text("Your Score"), message: Text("\(self.searchText)"))
                        }
                        ForEach(self.cars.filter {
                            self.searchText.isEmpty ? true : $0.name.lowercased().contains(self.searchText.lowercased())
                        }.indices, id: \.self) { idx in
                            ZStack (alignment: .leading) {
                                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5, style: .continuous)
                                    .fill(Color.white).shadow(color:.green, radius: 5).padding(.leading).padding(.trailing)
                                HStack {
                                    VStack (alignment: .leading) {
                                        Text(self.cars[idx].name)
                                        CatalogAvailable()
                                    }.padding(.leading).padding(.trailing)
                                    Toggle(isOn: self.$cars[idx].selected) {
                                        Text("")
                                    }.toggleStyle(CheckboxToggleStyle()).labelsHidden()
                                        .frame(width: 10, height: 10, alignment: .trailing).padding()
                                }.padding().frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                                
                            }.onTapGesture {
                                self.cars[idx].selected.toggle()
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }.navigationBarTitle("Add your cars")
                Button(action: {
                    print("Button tapped!")
                }) {
                    Text("Next")
                }.padding(.bottom)
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know SwiftUI handles it differently but sounds like you need to have 2 datasets. One for list and other for search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You iterate over `indices` but after filtering they do not correspond to original array, but just ordered indices of filtered array. You have to work with `id` of cars instead

Here is a sketch of idea:

```
ForEach(self.cars.filter {
    self.searchText.isEmpty ? true : $0.name.lowercased().contains(self.searchText.lowercased())
}) { car in
   self.row(for: car)
}

...

func row(for car: Car) -> some View {
  let idx = self.cars.firstIndex(of car)!

  return ZStack (alignment: .leading) {
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5, style: .continuous)
            .fill(Color.white).shadow(color:.green, radius: 5).padding(.leading).padding(.trailing)
        HStack {
            VStack (alignment: .leading) {
                Text(self.cars[idx].name)
                CatalogAvailable()
            }.padding(.leading).padding(.trailing)
            Toggle(isOn: self.$cars[idx].selected) {
                Text("")
            }.toggleStyle(CheckboxToggleStyle()).labelsHidden()
                .frame(width: 10, height: 10, alignment: .trailing).padding()
        }.padding().frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
        
    }.onTapGesture {
        self.cars[idx].selected.toggle()
    }

}
```